# expressjs modify/add a object proprerty in module

Tags: node.js, express, module

I create this module on express:

```
module.exports = {
 myobj : {},
 myfun : function(app) {

  app.all('/',function (req, res, next) {
   this.myobj.foo = ‘bar’;
  }
 }
}
```

But it doesn’t works, I received the following error   :
*Cannot set property ‘foo’ of undefined*

But I if I do this,This works well, why ?:

```
module.exports = {
 myobj : ‘’,
 myfun : function(app) {
 app.all('/',function (req, res, next) {
   this.myobj = ‘bar’;
  }
 }
}
```

I don’t understand why I can’t add a property to my object (first case) but I can modify my var myobj (second case).

What’s wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
module.exports = {
 myobj : {},
 myfun : function(app) {
  var that = this;
  app.all('/',function (req, res, next) {
   that.myobj.foo = ‘bar’;
  }
 }
}
```

In first case: `this` references to callback function: `function(req, res, next){}` not to the object you are exporting, because of this `myobj` is undefined and you receive error while trying to access `foo` property of undefined object.

In second case: you initialize new property `myobj` of `function(req, res, next) {}` callback and it's ok, you can do it, but if you call `myfun` and then check `myobj` will see that it is still empty string this happens because you modify callback function property not exported object.

Comment: Thanks !it's works and your answer it's really clear.